# Rebuilding the apk file with the different ID and/or Key : Native Script

Tags: android, nativescript, apk

I have a requirement to upload an apk file to a  newly created app in my Goolge Play Console. However there is already another older version of the same app  under a different name in my Play Console.

When I try to upload the apk file I get the following error.

> "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key
> that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because
> you are enrolled in App Signing by Google Play, you should sign your
> APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload it."

I have tried changing the ID of the app in the package.json file but it did not make any difference.

if I try to change app.gradle and deleted some auto generated files which had the old APP ID and rebuild it. But then I get the above error.

Any suggestions to fix this issue

Comment: You can't sign two different applications with the same keystore. You will have to delete the old application from the Play Store, or sign your new application with a different keystore.

Comment: Thank you HB. I was able to upload the app with a new keystore.